# Objective-c Code Blocks as nested method

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to have an nested method in Obj-c. What I an trying to do is create a specific object when initialising an `NSArray`:

```
NSArray array = @[
^{ NSViewController someObject = ... 

   someObject.someObjectProperty = @"Bla";

   return someObject}, 

^{ NSViewController someOtherObject = ... 

   someOtherObject.someOtherObjectProperty = @"Bla Bla";

   return someObject}, 
];
```

The array contains `__NSGlobalBlock__`, where I am trying to get `[someObject, someOtherObject]`

The array is returning a stack of ViewControllers and I need to set different properties on each of them.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what "nesting" and "synchronization" have to do with your array initialization. Can you go into a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am taken over a large solution, where they collect objects in a NSArray. I need to hook in and add some extra properties. It will make the readability easier.

Comment: I am not trying that hard but to me you're not making ANY sense... nested blocks and synchronisation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a local block and add its return value directly to the array. While it's not a mainstream method, it is possible:

```
NSArray *array = @[
  (id)^{
        id someObject = ...
        someObject.aProp = @"Bla"; 
        return someObject;
        }(), // here you immediately execute the local block
  (id)^{
        id someObject = ...
        someObject.aProp = @"Bla"; 
        return someObject;
        }()
];
```

Comment: Right on, thank you my friend :-) I am almost embarrassed I couldn't see it :-)

Comment: Well, @ChrisG., this is exactly what I already said. You were describing the block, not calling it. A call involves parentheses. So you were making an array consisting of blocks rather than an array consisting of the results of block calls.

Answer (score 2):

Code blocks are not just "for execution sometime in the future". They *can* be used that way, but they can certainly be used in the way you suggest; they are a lambda. Of course, you have the syntax all wrong, because you are *describing* the block, not *calling* it. (Though an array containing blocks is also perfectly reasonable.)

Comment: Hov would I call it within initializing the array?

Comment: So far I'm not convinced you even need a block call. Why not a method call? Actually I'm not even convinced you need a method call. If you just want to insert objects into your array, why don't you just insert them? You still have not explained anything of what you really want to do.